# Control multiple fills and strokes of an SVG with a function

Tags: javascript, svg, colors

So I've built a map with several different colored lines. I chopped up the lines into a string of segments at each dot.

What I'm trying to do is use javascript to change the colors of the lines and eventually move to being able to change the dynamically with a feed.

I made a color chart that I'm trying to get the line segment object to find its color and change to the proper corresponding color. The dots pulsate the fill color with greensock properly but the lines are giving me trouble. I keep getting an object isn't a function error.

I've tried a few different ways to set up the formula but I'm stuck.

```
var colorSet = {
  '#ff0000': '#ff6666',
  '#008250': '#42a680',
  '#a3238f': '#bd73b2',
  '#0079c2': '#42a0db',
  '#ff8c00': '#ffba66',
  '#96c800': '#cae087',
  '#a86000': '#c28f4e',
  '#999999': '#cccccc',
  '#ffe000': '#fff399'
}
var animateThis = function(obj) {
  var getStroke = obj.getAttribute('stroke');
  TweenLite.to(obj, 1.5, {
    fill: "#bbbbbb",
    yoyo: true,
    repeat: -1
  });
};
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Spiderian/hzafm6vk/3/#&togetherjs=6e0qwPovaP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To color lines you need to use `stroke`, not `fill`. And on `<line>` not on `<g>`.
2. `getStroke` is not used in you code. (And there is no `getAttribute` on `$` by the way. There is `attr()`)
3. `colorSet` also unused, and I don't really understand what is it for. As all of lines and points in the *jsfiddle* you've provided are of the same color.
4. Don't really understand why there are two lines for each `<g>`.

But nevertheless here is what you need to do:

```js
// change all line selectors from this
// const lsSIT0001 = $("#SIT0001");
// const lsSIT0002 = $("#SIT0002");
// ...
// to this
const lsSIT0001 = $("#SIT0001 line");
const lsSIT0002 = $("#SIT0002 line");
// ...
// because you need to change stroke color of `<line>`s, not `<g>`s

// split
// var itemsToAnimate = [ lsSIT0020, ..., lsSIT0001, SIR4947, ..., SIR4629 ]
// into
const linesToAnimate  = [ lsSIT0020, ..., lsSIT0001 ]
const pointsToAnimate = [ SIR4947  , ..., SIR4629   ]

// run separate animations for lines and dots
const animatePoints = obj => TweenLite.to(obj, 1.5, { fill  : "#ff0000", yoyo: true, repeat: -1 })
const animateLines  = obj => TweenLite.to(obj, 1.5, { stroke: "#0000ff", yoyo: true, repeat: -1 })
linesToAnimate .forEach(animateLines )
pointsToAnimate.forEach(animatePoints)
```

**Update:**
To use `colorSet` you need to either

- set `style='stroke: some_color'` on each `<line>` and then use it like this:

  ```
  const style = obj.eq(i).attr('style')
  // `i` is the index of a line inside <g> the color of which you want to get
  TweenLite.to(obj, 1.5, { stroke: colorSet[style], ... })
  ```

  In this case `colorSet` should look like

  ```
  const colorSet = {
    "stroke: #ff0000": '#ff6666',
    ...
    "stroke: #ffe000": '#fff399',
  }
  ```
- or get computed styles with `obj.get(i).computedStyleMap().get("stroke").toString()`
  In this case `colorSet` should look like

  ```
  const colorSet = {
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)": '#ff6666',
    ...
    "rgb(255, 224, 0)": '#fff399',
  }
  ```

  But it's [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap). So probably don't :)
- Or better yet - make a map not from color to color but from ids to color:

  ```
  const colorSet = {
    "#SIT0001": '#ff6666',
    ...
    "#SIT0020": '#fff399',
  }
  ```

  Then you won't need to get colors from DOM.

Comment: 1. You're right, I needed to move the id to the line from the group.

2. The full version has 9 colored lines and I need to get the stroke color, and then change it to the proper color.

3. The colorset is because I stripped this example down from 9 lines of different colors to focus on what I was having problems with.

4. One line is blue and 3 pixels wide, the other is white and 3.7 pixels wide, so when it's on different colored backgrounds it's still legible.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: The ids one is out. There are almost 1700 line segments. I'm going to try the computed style one, I would like to just be able to dump things in the two arrays and it will just work right.

Comment: It's up to you. But about ids: you do generate this SVG rigth? If so, that means that somewhere you set ids and set classes of `<line>`s, and that means that you can generate `colorSet` at the same time at the same place.

Comment: But then I can't turn of only specific sections of the line. It would always be one color or another.

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle but I can't get the animation to fire. https://jsfiddle.net/Spiderian/wxe4jzbp/4/

Comment: Check the console. `TweenLite is not defined` You need to add a link to the lib in *Resources* E.g. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js But After that you'll get `style is not defined`. Also you haven't changed `colorSet` so `colorSet[style]` will return `undefined`. And why you've removed `yoyo: true, repeat: -1`?

Comment: It works. Thanks, I removed the yoyo: true because not everything needs to blink.